# Spring Security 6 - OpenApi return HTTP ERROR 403 *Fixed

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, openapi

I have just started learning Spring Security. I can access it with Postman, but I can't reach it with OpenApi. What could be the issue? It was working before I updated and added Security.
**Spring Boot vers 3.0.6**
**Spring Security vers 6**.
Here is my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder encoder){
        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("msg")
                .password(encoder.encode("123"))
                .roles("ADMIN", "USER")
                .build();
        UserDetails user = User.withUsername("user")
                .password(encoder.encode("123"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin, user);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        return http.httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                //.requestMatchers("/users").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/users/**").hasRole("USER")
                .requestMatchers("/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I added the 'springdoc-openapi-security' later because it was not working. However, even after adding it, it is still not working.

OpenAPI is sending an HTTP 403 error for all requests. The URL is http://localhost:9090/swagger-ui.html.

**Edit***

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Open API new version. This is the version supported by Spring Boot 3.0. When I changed it, everything was fixed.

Comment: why not just enable debug logs and look for the exact reason in the logs for why you are getting a 403?

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thank you for your advice, I followed your suggestions.
I added the logs to the question. Can you check them? I couldn't fully understand where the mistake is.

Comment: "with postman its working" you are not doing the same thing with postman, you are fetching `/users` not `swagger-ui.html` so how can you claim its working? try whitelisting `/error` endpoint

Comment: I did what you suggested and /error returned a 404 error to me. After doing some research, I found out that in Spring Boot 3, OpenAPI has been upgraded to a new version. When I changed the dependency, it gave me the correct output.  Thanks to you, I learned how to look at the log history and now I can approach things from different perspectives. Thank you again.

Comment: logs are your best friend